# What is the same as `R` (generics) in Rust?

Tags: java, generics, rust

What is equivalent Java's `R` (stands for `Return`) in rust?

For example, how can I write something like this in Rust?

```
<R> R accept(Visitor<R> visitor) {
    return visitor.visitAssignExpr(this);
}
```

Relating to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449519/what-do-the-type-parameter-names-p-and-r-mean-and-how-are-they-used).

Comment: Don't tag spam. Rust also has [generics](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-01-syntax.html). What are you asking?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The equivalent in Rust would be:

```rust
fn accept<R>(&self, visitor: Visitor<R>) -> R {
    visitor.visit_assign_expr(self)
}
```

The `R` is just an identifier; it doesn't mean anything special and could've just as easily been `T` or `Return`. In Rust, the list of generics for a function go between the function name and the parameters. Note: I've made other changes in syntax and convention.

Beyond syntax, Rust's generics may behave or be constrained differently than they are in Java. Consider reading through the [Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/title-page.html), it has a chapter on [Generic Data Types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-01-syntax.html).

See also:

- [Does Rust erase generic types or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32546054/does-rust-erase-generic-types-or-not)
- [Is Rust trait the same as Java interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69477460/is-rust-trait-the-same-as-java-interface)